# what should a equals method return if both objects compared are null?

Tags: java, null, equals

I used the Eclipse auto-tool for implementing equals method for a person Object.
if two persons objects, `p1` and `p2` are `null`, what should `p1.equals(p2)` return?
The current implementation provided my Eclipse returns `True`. However, I tried comparing to `null` string object, and it throws `NullPointerException.` Here is the code. Also I want to know why the code on different runs gives different results. I pasted the output below

```
class Parent2 {
private String name;
private int id;
public static int count = 0;

public Parent2(String name, int id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    if (this.getClass() == Parent2.class)
        count++;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + id;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Parent2 other = (Parent2) obj;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null) {
            System.out.println("here2");
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name)) {
        System.out.println("here");
        return false;
    }
    return true;


}

}

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent2 par = new Parent2("aa", 5);
        Parent2 par2 = new Parent2(null, 5);
        Parent2 par3 = new Parent2(null, 5);

    System.out.println(par.equals(par2));
    System.out.println(par2.equals(par));
    System.out.println(par3.equals(par2));

    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

    String str = null;
    String str2 = null;

    System.out.println(str.equals(str2));
    System.out.println(str + "; " + str2);
}
```

}

The outputs are different on each executions, here are a few:

```
here
false
here2Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at RoundTwo.App.main(App.java:64)

false
true
----------------------------------------
```

output2:

```
here
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at RoundTwo.App.main(App.java:64)
false
here2
false
true
----------------------------------------
```

ouput3:

```
here
false
here2
false
true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at RoundTwo.App.main(App.java:64)
----------------------------------------
```

ouput4:

```
here
falseException in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at RoundTwo.App.main(App.java:64)

here2
false
true
----------------------------------------
```

ouput5:

```
here
false
here2
false
true
----------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at RoundTwo.App.main(App.java:64)
```

only the last ouput, executes the `string equals` part of the code which throws `NullpointerException`

Thanks for helping out

Comment: You cannot ever call a method on a `null` object; Java will throw a `NullPointerException` before it even gets to your code.  You cannot prevent it in the `equals` method itself; you must prevent it before it's called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other people have stated, executing any operation on a `null` variable raises a `NullPointerException`. I guess this is the main problem in your question:

> only the last ouput, executes the string equals part of the code which throws `NullpointerException`

This is wrong. The fact that you're seeing different outputs at each execution is because `System.out.println()` writes on `System.out` PrintStream while the `RuntimeException`s, like `NullPointerException`, are write in `System.err` PrintStream. Both streams end writing on the same console but there's no guarantee about the time they will flush their content. If you want to see how this behaves, use a single buffer to print everything, including the exceptions, like using loggers instead of plain `System.out` calls. A basic sample would be:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Parent2 par = new Parent2("aa", 5);
        Parent2 par2 = new Parent2(null, 5);
        Parent2 par3 = new Parent2(null, 5);

    System.out.println(par.equals(par2));
    System.out.println(par2.equals(par));
    System.out.println(par3.equals(par2));

    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

    String str = null;
    String str2 = null;

    System.out.println(str.equals(str2));
    System.out.println(str + "; " + str2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //this will do the "trick"
        e.printStacktrace(System.out);
    }
    }
}
```

Now, on every execution of your application you a single result:

```
here
false
here2
false
true
----------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at RoundTwo.App.main(App.java:64)
```

---

> However, I tried comparing to null string object, and it throws NullPointerException.

Do the same with your `p1` and `p2` objects and you'll see the `NullPointerException` arise. From the code above:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Parent2 par = new Parent2("aa", 5);
        Parent2 par2 = new Parent2(null, 5);
        Parent2 par3 = new Parent2(null, 5);
    par = null;
    par2 = null;
    System.out.println(par.equals(par2)); // <-- NPE here
    System.out.println(par2.equals(par));
    System.out.println(par3.equals(par2));

    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

    String str = null;
    String str2 = null;

    System.out.println(str.equals(str2));
    System.out.println(str + "; " + str2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //this will do the "trick"
        e.printStacktrace(System.out);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I now see what is going on. Thanks for pointing it out on the code..

Comment: Is it correct to say that `this` can be `null` but it will throw `NPE` even before it executes the `equal` method. so `this` can be null in some cases right?

Comment: @user1988876 no, that's not correct. There is **no** case when `this` variable will be `null`.

Answer (score 4):

**In general:** If the control flow is already inside an instance method, the instance on which the method was invoked on is not null.

So inside your `equals` method both objects can not be `null`, as the control flow is **already inside** the instance method. The reference `this` can **never** be `null`. (in static context, it is unavailable, and using it results in a compiler error)

However, your immediate problem is that the execution will *not even enter your `equals` method* if the object on which the equality check is to be performed is null - you can not call an instance method on a `null` object: you get a `NullPointerException`.

#### Other cases involving nulls

A `Comparator` instance however **should** deal with such a situation: in that case, it should return `0`.

#### Strange behaviour of console output

The order of the messages on the console differs, because you write to two different streams: `System.err` and `System.out`. In such a situation it is not guaranteed that the order of the printed messages is the same as the order they have been written...

Answer (score 3):

if both P1 and P2 are null it should return `NullPointerException` as you can't call equals method on a `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to consider this case in the method. If `this` is `null` the `NullPointerException` automatically and it's not possible to override this behaviour.

With method overloading the exact method that will be called on `o1.equals(o2)` depends on *runtime* type of `o1`. Since `null` does not have runtime type (there is no object) there is no method that can be called. Hence it will *always* throw `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

> > if two persons objects, p1 and p2 are null, what should p1.equals(p2) return?

It results in a `NullPointerException`